# How to update records with same ID in same table in MysQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Table1` which has data like

```
-------------------------------
code     value
-------------------------------
02      null
05      null
06      hi
02      hello
05      how
```

I want to update the same table as

```
-------------------------------
id     value
-------------------------------
02      hello
05      how
06      hi
02      hello
05     how
```

I used the following query, but is not working:

```
update Table1 set value=value where id is null
```

Comment: a id must be unique. Why you have it multiple times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: Can't you use id as `primary key`? A id must be unique.

Comment: Note that you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may well prove to be problematic in due course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create alias of the Table1 and than set value into null record as below:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1, (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, value 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND value != ''
) t2 SET t1.value = t2.value 
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

**Above query is tested and working.**

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join` to connect the two tables (correlated subqueries are tricky in MySQL update statements):

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select id, min(value) as value
        from table1
        group by id
       ) tt1
       on t1.id = tt.id
    set t1.value = tt1.value
    where t1.value is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a simpler syntax:

```
update t1 from table1 t1, table2 t2 set t1.value=t2.value where t1.code=t2.id
```

Tho I havent tested it right now.

Comment: For this specific example, this may well be correct, but I don't think this solution scales up to a more general answer.

Answer (score -1):

Query should be written as:

update Table1 set value=' ' where id = 1.

Here value is the column name and you like to update some content(hi, hello etc) to it. If the content is String, then enclose it with single/double quotes. For what row you want to update that comes after WHERE clause. Here you are setting condition as WHERE id = 1. So for id =1, the value gets updated.

Comment: It looks like the question may be worded incorrectly for the results they're after.  The only difference between before and after I can see is that the 'code' column has become an 'id' column.  Instead of an update I think the user is after an alter table statement.

Answer (score -1):

Generate a script with a SELECT statement and execute it (don't forget commit at the end):

```
select concat('update Table1 set value=`', value, '` where id =', id, ';') as script from Table1 where value is not null;
```